# Web API OData - dates and daylight savings

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a database table containing (amongst other fields) a date, and a value.
There is a record for every day of the year, the sub sets below contain the 2015 date range when daylight savings (British Summer Time) starts and ends:

```
Source Data:
ID     Date (dd/mm/yyyy)     Value
...    ...                   ...
8E5    27/03/2015            600
8F5    28/03/2015            600
905    29/03/2015            600  // DST Starts
915    30/03/2015            600
925    31/03/2015            600
...    ...                   ...    
615    24/10/2015            600
625    25/10/2015            600  // DST Ends
635    26/10/2015            600
645    27/10/2015            600
```

I'm using Web API OData to return data from this table, and here is the JSON response for the same date range:

```
...
{
  "Id":"8E5",
  "CostDate":"2015-03-27T00:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
},{
  "Id":"8F5",
  "CostDate":"2015-03-28T00:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
},{
  "Id":"905",
  "CostDate":"2015-03-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
},{
  "Id":"915",                              // Duplicate 29/03/2015, ID field out of sync
  "CostDate":"2015-03-29T23:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
},{
  "Id":"925",
  "CostDate":"2015-03-30T23:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
}
...
{
  "Id":"625",
  "CostDate":"2015-10-24T23:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
},{
  "Id":"635",                              // Missing 25/10/2015?
  "CostDate":"2015-10-26T00:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
},{
  "Id":"645",
  "CostDate":"2015-10-27T00:00:00Z",
  "Value":600
}
...
```

Notice the duplicate 29th March? From that date onward the ID is out of sync with the source data, and there is also a missing 25th October.

My assumption is that when the data is being serialised to JSON, there is something happening with local vs UTC time.

If I remove OData from the equation and use normal Web API, I cannot re-create the problem, it appears that the issue is with OData or the JSON Formatter.

What do I need to do to get the dates as they appear in the source data?

**Code** (if relevant):

```
public class BudgetDto
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CostDate { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class BudgetsController : ODataController
{    
    private IBudgetService BudgetService { get; }

    public BudgetsController(IBudgetService budgetService)
    {
        BudgetService = budgetService;
    }

    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 400)]
    public IQueryable<BudgetDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<BudgetDto> queryOptions)
    {
        return BudgetService.Budgets(queryOptions);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
This link appears to shed a little light on the issue:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/11/28/time-travel-with-net-or-datetime-datetimeoffset-and-the-lost-dst-hour-greg.aspx

While my model uses `DateTime` as the type, OData is switching to `DateTimeOffset`, perhaps this explains the difference between OData and Web API, where the former does not support `DateTime` and the latter which does.

**UPDATE 2**
The `DateTimeOffset` has a [LocalDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) property which contains the correct dates as per the source data.  What I don't understand is that the source data does not have any time zone info on it, and the JSON returned is UTC (see the 'Z' at the end of the time stamps?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData V4 doesn't include `DateTime` as its standard edm type. In Web API, DateTime is mapped to DateTimeOffset.

If you want to use DateTime, please make sure you have set the TimeZoneInfo, otherwise, it will use the local setting.

More information, please refer to the [sample page](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-01-datetime-support) from odata team.